# Xcode doesn't recognize GoogleService-Info.plist file after adding Firebase via pods

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to add Firebase and I keep getting a log message thats says:

> Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.

I added the file in Xcode by way of `File > Add new file to project`.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: In your screenshot it looks like the file name includes (7). What is that for? Also, you could try clearing your build cache (Command-Option-Shift-K) in Xcode.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It happens to me. Just erase the **(7)**. The Xcode firebase framework connects to firebase through the `GoogleService-Info.plist` when you build your code an error will be display if the .plist file is not called exactly: `GoogleService-Info.plist`. At the moment that the .plist file has another character in the name, the firebase framework will not recognize it. The framework is searching just for the **GoogleService-Info.plist** not **GoogleService-Info.plist (07)**

This usually happens when you download several times your GoogleService-Info.plist
from the console. If you want to avoid this. Get the file out from your "downloads" carpet.  Otherwise, your computer is going to add a number at the end of the name file if you already have one inside that carpet. It creates a copy.

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 75):

To anyone still having this issue:

1. Add the file to the project
2. Click on it:

[image]

3. On the right sidebar from Xcode, mark the `Target Membership` option:

[image]

Comment: You rock.  That totally solved it. How did you figure that out?

Comment: I did the same thing. Now it is not crashing at all.

Comment: Oh man, your solution saved me, I was going mad, as this issue took 4,5 hours of me.

Comment: Glad to know guys! 

Comment: how to support for 3 different plist file with different names ?

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed Maybe this article will help: https://medium.com/@brunolemos/how-to-setup-a-different-firebase-project-for-debug-and-release-environments-157b40512164

Answer (score 18):

I solved this by using these steps :

1. Go to Build Phases of your project
   [image]
2. Expand "Copy Bundle Resources"
3. Click on Plus (+) button and add "GoogleService-Info.plist" file.

clean and build your project.

Comment: I've done this but not working any other things I can do?

Comment: make sure that your file name is "GoogleService-Info.plist" not "GoogleService-Info-2.plist" or something.

Answer (score 6):

Change the `plist` name from `GoogleService-Info(7).plist` to `GoogleService-Info.plist`

Comment: The correct location of the file is at the same level as the info.plist. Also as @kye said, to that specific file you need to remove the (7)  and leave it as GoogleService-Info.plist

Answer (score 5):

This file should be in your project directory, not in pods directory.

Answer (score 5):

[image: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/5]

I had the same problem. I solved the problem by following the steps below
Source: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/5

Answer (score 3):

Rename your file `GoogleService-Info(7).plist` to `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

My experience:

google-service.plist was on the gitignore and the Xcode holds a reference to it (if did exists) it SHOULD NOT BE IN RED COLOR. that means the actual file is missing just add them back in each folder manually ( not through Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

Just Drag and drop GoogleService-Info.plist into xcode